# Magento 2 checkout extra fee is adding twice to base_grand_total

Tags: magento2, checkout, extrafee

magento 2 checkout  extra fee adding twice to grand total
collect function calling 4 to 5 times

```
parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
    if (!count($shippingAssignment->getItems())) {
        return $this;
    }
```

+

```
$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
    if($address->getAddressType() != 'billing'){
        return $this;
    }
    // My code
    return $this;
```

(or)

```
$address = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
    if($address->getAddressType() == 'billing'){

        // My code
        return $this;
    }
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42141291/8237294

Answer (score 3):

Please check if shipping assignment contain item(s) when it apply the extra fee:

```
$items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
```

Please add above code in collect method at very first like below:

```
public function collect(
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
\Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
) {
      $items = $shippingAssignment->getItems();
      if (!count($items)) {
           return $this;
      }
      parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

      /* your cusotm code ....*/

}
```

Comment: still adding twice